# Javascript absolute folder path from alias

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

How can I get the absolute path of a folder using alias? I'm using javascript with webpack.

My jsconfig file:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
}
```

What I need:

```js
let absolutePath = getAbsoluteFromAlias("@/my_folder") // absolutePath -> "/the_path_to_my_project/src/my_folder"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path');
const alias = path.resolve();

//...

"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        `${alias}/*`: ["src/*"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't actually change the jsconfig.json file, as there are already many other files in the project that depend on @/*.  I need something that translates '@/my_folder' to absolute path, resolving the alias.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.